# MongoDB, SpringData, findByPositionNear more parameters

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Hi have follow implementation:

```
public class Store {
   private double[] position;
   private String category;
}
```

And this method for search stores nears

```
public List<Store> fundByLatLong(double latitude, double longitude, Double km) {

mongoTemplate.indexOps(Store.class).ensureIndex(new GeospatialIndex("position"));

    Point point= new Point(latitude, longitude);

    List<Store> stores= this.storeRepository.findByPositionNear(ponto , new Distance(km, Metrics.KILOMETERS));

    return stores;
}
```

But i need search by position and category. How i can add param category for find?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
interface StoreRepository extends Repository<Store, Long> {

  List<Store> findByCategoryAndPositionNear(String category, 
                                            Point point, Distance distance);
}
```

More on this kind of stuff in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html).

Comment: Yes, but this interface is not native in SpringData the SpringData native interface is 

    findByPositionNear(Point p, Distance d)

The SpringData implements this interface in runtime. How i can tell SpringData to implements a interface that I need?

Comment: What do you mean by "not native"? The interface definition shown above just works out of the box. You can't tell Spring Data to implement an arbitrary interface. Your interface needs to adhere to the feature Spring Data supports or implement the parts of the repo yourself. All of this is documented in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html).